5-15p to L14-30R generator connection/single pole to double
Recently I received an electric backup generator that outputs 125v, 15A max using a 5-15r receptacle.  The cord to connect to the generator is a 5-15p but I was thinking of connecting to an existing L14-30P I have in my garage (connected to a double pole 30A breaker in the electrical cabinet).  Reason I'd want to do this is to power both poles in the cabinet instead of every other one.  If this were to happen, I would install an interlock switch in the panel so never would street power and generator power be possibly connected at the same time.  I know that I can never have any of the other double pole breakers on at the same time, and that's ok as the heat and fridge are single pole/15A's (drawing little power).
I found a 5-15p to L14-30R cable so I can connect the two but is this config safe?  The cable would connect the generator to the inlet, but is there any concern of overloading the neutral here or something else?  I appreciate your help here!

Do you have any multi-wire branch circuits? That's the operative question here...

No, no MWBC's anywhere in the house, every circuit has its own run going to a single pole breaker and everything running 240v is going to a dedicated double pole breaker.  If we flip to generator, nothing 240V would be powered by the generator, we'd keep those breakers off.

There are small transfer switch panels available that provide individual switches for a few breakers.

Are you should it is 5-15 to L14-30, or more likely a L14-30(plug) to 5-15s(receptacles)?  The second one will not connect to your gen.

Nema 5-15P Male L14-30R Female Power Adapter Cord,Household 15Amp to Generator Lock in 30Amp Adapter Cord,STW 12AWG

Might not need that cable.  Most panels have the top breaker on one pole/side.  The second one down is on the other pole/side, so if the heater and fridge are odd number breakers(1 and 3) you can make the connection more simple to a single pole/side of the panel.  Check the amps needed for the fridge/heater.  15 amp circuits(14 gauge wire) should be kept to about 12 amps for constant(heater) use.

There are too many unique breakers for my house that prevented me from moving them around.  I know how much I'll be able to use, and I'll have a monitor on the line to keep an eye on it, as I brin up each breaker.
